# Vue.js. Как получить доступ к полям из функции внутри объекта

Tags: javascript, vue.js

В подключаемом компоненте .vue имеется следующий код:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
template>
  <div>
    <VueSuggestions :model.sync="city"
                    :coordinates.sync="coordinates"
                    :placeholder="'Начните вводить'"
                    class="form-control"
                    :options="suggestionOptions">
    </VueSuggestions>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import VueSuggestions from 'vue-suggestions';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        city: '',
        coordinates: {
          latitude: '',
          longitude: ''
        },
        suggestionOptions: {
          // @see https://confluence.hflabs.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=207454318
          token: '',
          type: "ADDRESS",
          scrollOnFocus: false,
          triggerSelectOnBlur: false,
          triggerSelectOnEnter: false,
          addon: 'spinner',
          floating: true,
          // @see https://confluence.hflabs.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=207454320
          onSelect(suggestion) {
            
          }
        },
      }
    },
    components: { VueSuggestions },
    props: {
      daDataResults: []
    },
    computed: {
      addNumber() {
        alert(this.suggestionOptions.onSelect());
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Никак не пойму, как в методе внутри data.suggestionOptions в методе onSelect(suggestion) добраться до других полей в data или до блока methods (код приведен без него).

Если кто знает - подскажите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Также через this и в соответствии в каком контексте запустите, то будут доступны соответствующие объекты ([подробнее](https://learn.javascript.ru/bind) о контексте в js). Другой вопрос: зачем вам такая структура? Почему нельзя вынести `onSelect` в методы компонента.

```
suggestionOptions: {
  // @see https://confluence.hflabs.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=207454318
  token: '',
  type: "ADDRESS",
  scrollOnFocus: false,
  triggerSelectOnBlur: false,
  triggerSelectOnEnter: false,
  addon: 'spinner',
  floating: true,
  // @see https://confluence.hflabs.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=207454320
  onSelect(suggestion) {
    console.log(this.suggestionOptions.token);
    console.log(this.city);
    return 'It is works!';
  }
},
```

И вызов

```
computed: {
      addNumber() {
        alert(this.suggestionOptions.onSelect.call(this));
      }
    },
```